# Video site URL?

Tags: php, url, video, header, location

I have a video site
example: `site.com/page5/` i have 5 page video.

But if I write url `site.com/page50000000/` query returns.

```
<?
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
include 'fonksiyon.php';
$say=mysql_query("select * from videos");
$saydim=mysql_num_rows($say);
$count = $saydim;
$perpage = 16;
$page = !empty($_GET["page"]) ? intval($_GET["page"]) : 1;
$s = ($page-1)*$perpage; 
$lastP = ceil($count/$perpage);
?>
```

I wanted do with `header("Location:index.php");` with redirect to main page.

So if I write `site.com/page100/`, I want to redirect to my `index.php`, this is because I have 5 page video.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: fyi: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you should use `mysqli_*` or PDO